# How can I use Vercel rest API to create a deployment on a new project?

Tags: rest, next.js, deployment, vercel

I have a Node.js codebase that I am using to create a new project in Vercel based on data provided from a CMS. I was able to get the project to be created using Vercel's REST API but it does not have any deployments when I look at the project in Vercel. I would like it to automatically deploy (using the GitHub repo the project is attached to) like when you manually create a project in Vercel. When I found the REST API option in the docs the "create a new deployment" option has hundreds of things required in the request that I do not understand https://vercel.com/docs/rest-api/endpoints#create-a-new-deployment . I am wondering if there is a more simple way to force a deployment on a project using things like (project name, teamid, authorization token).

Answer (score 1):

First, to create a project from github we need 2 steps:

- Create project through api [#create-a-new-project](https://vercel.com/docs/rest-api/endpoints#create-a-new-project)
- Create deployment via api [#create-a-new-deployment](https://vercel.com/docs/rest-api/endpoints#create-a-new-deployment)

Below is a specific example when I use the `javascript` `fetch` function

```js
const data = {
    name: "project-name",
    environmentVariables: [
        {
            key: "YOUR_FIRST_ENV",
            value: "DATA_OF_FIRST_ENV",
            target: ["production"],
            type: "plain",
        },
        //...
    ],
    framework: "nextjs",
    gitRepository: {
        type: "github",
        repo: "username/repo_name",
    },
} 
const apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"

const res = await fetch(
    "https://api.vercel.com/v9/projects",
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`       
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
);

const project = await res.json();
const deployRes = await fetch(
    "https://api.vercel.com/v13/deployments",
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`       
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "gitSource" : {
                "ref" : "main",
                "repoId" : project.link.repoId,
                "type" : "github"
            },
            "name": data.name,
            "projectSettings" : {
                "framework" : data.framework
            }
        })
    }
);
```